# PHP Delete Record after 7 Days?

Tags: php, datetime, unix, date, unix-timestamp

I want to delete records from a database when they are 7 days or older. I have my server time set to UK time but for some reason the code I wrote below always echo's **Account Deleted as 7 or more days old** and for some reason it's not working. Before I test on my test database I decided to use a simple echo for now, but as I say it won't work.

Anyone have any suggestions why it's not working? I must be doing something wrong.

```
<?php

// Get Current Time
$current_time = time();

/* The time i used below (unix) for testing is 
18-02-2011 14:34:24 (yesterdays date/time) */
$account_delete = strtotime(time('1298039664'));

if ($current_time - $account_delete >= (7*24*60*60)){
echo 'Account Deleted as 7 or more days old';
} else {
  echo 'Account Not Deleted as less than 7 days old';
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't think that you implemented the delete row function.

Comment: Why are you storing your timestamps as UNIX timestamps instead of using a real DATETIME type?

Comment: @ahonorstudent I have not created that code yet i just done it like above for now to see if it echos' out correctly before using on database. It should say account not deleted as the sample time i used is only yesterdays date/time.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen personally i prefer unix timestamp. I know it will eventually stop working in 2038 i think but i personally prefer it myself, i have never used the mysql date functions etc as never been able to find good tutorials explaining how to use so until i do i will stick with unix, unless you know of any good tutorials ?. Thanks PHPLOVER

Comment: @PHPLOVER: The MySQL documentation would be a good place to start.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen i have been there many times before and i find it to overwhelming and the pages alone confuses me which so much information on them, i need simple tutorials that explains things easily lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `strtotime(time('1298039664'))` with `1298039664`?

time() does not take any parameters.

Comment: Oh dear i need to go to specsavers lol. Thanks arex1337. I did not need to use strtotime as it is already unix format duh! thanks for solving it for me.